# c++: how to use char / string 2d array to accept more than 1 sentense from an user?

Tags: c++

**Below code failed:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a, b;
    cout << "how many input you want to give ? ";
    cin >> a;
    b = a - 1;
    string str[b];            
    for(int i = 0; i <= b; i++){
        cout << "Enter a string: ";
        getline(cin, str[i]);
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < a; k++){
        cout << "You entered: " << str[k] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**But if I fix the value of 'int a' then the code is running. please help.**

Answer (score 0):

Arrays must have a constant size at compile-time so to create an array with dynamic size you can create it on the heap using keyword `new` and `delete[]` to free up memory.

Also what is the point in:

```
cin >> a;
b = a - 1; //?
```

You can easily do it like this:

```
int n;
cout << "how many input you want to give ? ";
cin >> n;
string* str = new string[n];            
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(cin, str[i]);
}

for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
    cout << "You entered: " << str[k] << endl;
}
```

Don't forget to clean when you're done:

```
delete[] str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to clear the input buffer, the newline from "How many input you want to give ?" is being fed into the first "Enter a string:".

Add this line after cin>>a;

```
cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a vector to store the input.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using names pace std;

int main ()
{
   vector <string> input;
   string tmp;

   while (getline(cin, tmp))
      input.push_back(tmp));

   for(auto s : input)
      cout << s << '\n';
}
```